# Parsing xml into anonymous type

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to parse the xml below to load the id_name/rel_no pairs into an anonymous type collection. I am having a problem when looping through the collection and when  element is missing in one of the  elements. Is there a way not to load a particular pair when one of the elements id_name or rel_no is missing?

I get InvalidOperationException (sequence contains no elements) when the loop gets to that particular pair with missing element.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
XDocument xdata = XDocument.Parse(data);

var query = from dox in xdata.Descendants("Inc")
                        select new
                        {
                            IDName= dox.Element("id_name").Value,
                            RelNo= dox.Descendants("rel_no").First().Value
                        };
```

XML

```
<Data>

<Inc>
    <id_name>test</id_name> 
    <Relationships>
        <Relationship>
            <rel_no>004</rel_no> 
        </Relationship>
    </Relationships>
</Inc>
<Inc>
    <id_name>test2</id_name> 
    <Relationships>
        <Relationship>
        </Relationship>
    </Relationships>
</Inc>
<Inc>
    <id_name>test3</id_name> 
    <Relationships>
        <Relationship>
            <rel_no>006</rel_no> 
        </Relationship>
    </Relationships>
</Inc>

</Data>
```

Accessing in a loop

```
foreach (var record in query)
            {
            }
```

Comment: First() will throw this exception if can't find any element, Try using FirstOrDefault() that will return null if the item doesn't exist

Comment: How about posting a correct xml? `<id_name>test</case_no>`

Comment: Sorry I have corrected the xml

Comment: Actually I tried using FirstOrDefault() and it threw NullReference exception in foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var xdata = XDocument.Parse(data);
var items = xdata.Descendants("Inc")
            .Select(d => new
            {
                DName = (string)d.Element("id_name"),
                RelNo = ((string)d.Descendants("rel_no").FirstOrDefault() ?? "")
            })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. I can check for empty string now inside the loop.